# C# dll as an ActiveX control to access GPS data in Windows Mobile 6.1 IE

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, activex, gps

Is it possible using VS2008 and C# to create a class library which can be treated as an ActiveX control on a Windows Mobile 6/6.1 device?

I am looking to retrieve the positioning details from a device so I can post the current location on a google map. I have this all working nicely as a application but I need to expose the same functionality from just from a web page so I think I am going to have to use an ActiveX control?

If there are any alternative approaches I could take that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Since the CF lacks EE Hosting support, there's no way to create a COM/ActiveX control in managed code.  You'll have to write in in C++ - there's just no other option.